# Imagemagick: How to create a multy-layered tiff from all png files in the given folder using bash

Tags: bash, imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I have a lot of PNG kept in a folder, and need to convert them all into single multy-layered TIFF using ImageMagick.

When I run this command on a desktop Windows, I get the needed TIFF.

```
magick *.png -compress lzw -adjoin out.tiff
```

But when I run it on a Unix Server using bash script, it doesn't work and produces TIFF with single image only.

How to correct this error?

Comment: Your command works fine on ImageMagick 7.1 Try running `magick -version` on your Unix box.

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-15

Comment: Imagemagick does not make layers TIFFs, only multi-page TIFFs.  Your command with -adjoin should work fine. Use +adjoin to force each image to be written to separate files.

Comment: Your command works fine for me on Mac OSX with IM 7.1.1.19.